# Firebird locking with EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, firebird

I created simple WinForms application that connect to Firebird server using EntityFramework. Database contains only one table with 4 fields (Id, FirstName, LastName, Email).
When I run in parallel thre different query for update different field I've got exception with message "lock conflict on no wait transaction".
Is it EF specific behavior or I need to tune firebird server for usage field level locking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error if you are updating the same row in multiple transactions at the same time. There is no such thing as field level locking in Firebird, as the row as a whole is versioned.

The only solutions available to you are: don't do this, update all fields in a single query, add a retry mechanism, or don't fire updates of different fields in parallel.